# Error when opening up Dynamics Workflow file ( .xaml ) in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation

When I try to open up an .xaml file, the designer only shows a red box with "Could not generate view for Workflow"

Here's the steps I took:

1. create a simple workflow in Dynamics CRM 2011, it has only one if condition, and a send email step
2. add the workflow to a solution, and exported the solution as unmanaged.
3. In Visual Studio 2012, create a .NET 4 Activity Library
4. Right click on project, and add existing and select the xaml file exported in the solution
5. Double click on the .xaml file to view it in designer

The tutorials I'm following are all using Visual Studio 2010, makes me wonder if something is broken in VS 2012.

Edit: the actual exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.ReferenceLiteral`1.CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
>          at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadataExceptResult(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
>          at System.Activities.Activity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
>          at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
>          at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
>          at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
>          at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
>          at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidationServices.InternalValidate()
>          at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.Validate(Activity toValidate, ValidationSettings settings)
>          at System.Activities.Presentation.Validation.ValidationService.CoreValidationWork(ValidationReason reason, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Well, the GUI has been broken for sure. So ugly... :)

Comment: I'm getting the same error in VS 2010 as well as VS 2012. Would love to have an answer since the CRM folks don't allow us to edit workflows by any other means than exporting the solution, hacking, then reimporting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found is to downgrade to CRM SDK version 1.0 (not 1.1 from current release). Then in VS 2010 works.